# How to construct a simple matrix and change values according to equation (numpy)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix, numpy-ndarray

My question is really simple. I have to make a 5*5 matrix and each i,j value should follow a formula of i+j

I have this so far:
'''

```html
w = np.zeros(shape=(5,5))
print(w)


for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        w[i][j] == i**2+j
        
print(w)
```

But Its just returning a 0 matrix right now what to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change

```
w[i][j] == i**2+j
```

to (if you want to keep the formular)

```
w[i,j] = i**2+j
```

or use the formular from your question

```
w[i,j] = i+j
```

If you want to get rid of the loops, you can use numpy

```
w = np.arange(5)
w = np.add.outer(w ** 2, w)
print(w)
```

Out:

```
[[ 0  1  2  3  4]
 [ 1  2  3  4  5]
 [ 4  5  6  7  8]
 [ 9 10 11 12 13]
 [16 17 18 19 20]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very helpful.